# How to exec function when navigating away from a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to execute a function when the user navigates to a different screen ... I tried executing it inside `componentWillUnmount`, but the component doesn't `unmount` on `navigation.navigate`

```
  intervalId = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    const me = this;

    //alert(JSON.stringify(me.props.navigation));
    alert(route.name);
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {

      //if (this.props.navigation.state.routeName==)
      //this.getOrders();
    }, 3000);
    //alert("llamada");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    //alert("CAMBIANDO");
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
```

Comment: What function you want to exec in componentWillUnmount? ... Do you mean you want to unUmount the component after navigation to a different component ?

Comment: clearInterval(this.intervalId). I want to clear the interval, but when i dot navigate 'componentWillUnmount' doesn't execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop your timer when 1. The `componentWillUnmount`, and 2. The component loses focus (`didBlur` event)

and when your component receives-focus back again ( `didFocus` event ), you could re-enable your `timer`

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';


  <NavigationEvents
    onDidBlur={() => {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }}
    onDidFocus={() => {
      /** Re-enable timer here */
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {...
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks you,and how can i make to execute again the interval when i come back from the navigate?